# perform principal component analysis on moving window of data

Tags: python-3.x, pca, rolling-computation

This was partly answered by [@WhoIsJack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8300815/whoisjack) but not completely solved given the errors I get. Basically, I'm trying to perform principal component analysis on a rolling window of data. For example, I'd run PCA on the last 200 days in the df, move forward 1 day and do PCA again on the last 200 days. So as you move forward each day, you'd include the next day's measurement and exclude the last measurement.

You have a random df:

```
data = np.random.random(size=(1000,10))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Here's window size:

```
window = 200
```

Initialize an empty df of appropriate size for the output

```
df_pca = pd.DataFrame( np.zeros((data.shape[0] - window + 1, data.shape[1])) )
```

Define PCA fit-transform function. Instead of attempting to return the result, it is written into the previously created output array.

```
def rolling_pca(window_data):
    pca = PCA()
    transf = pca.fit_transform(df.iloc[window_data])
    df_pca.iloc[int(window_data[0])] = transf[0,:]
    return True
```

Create a df containing row indices for the workaround

```
df_idx = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(df.shape[0]))
```

Use rolling to apply the PCA function

```
_ = df_idx.rolling(window).apply(rolling_pca)
```

The results should be contained here:

```
print(df_pca)
```

However, when I generate the results only the first row of data looks to contain PCAs while the rest of the rows are zero.

I also tried the following function:

```
def rolling_pca(x, window):
    r   = x.rolling(window=window)
    pca = PCA(3)
    y   = pca.fit(r)
    z   = pca.fit_transform(y)
    return z

window = 200
```

Which I thought would generate a new df with rolling PCAs:

```
data = df.apply(rolling_pca, window=window)
```

But I got the following error: setting an array element with a sequence.

I've also tried manually calculating with below. I get: "unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Rolling' and 'int'"

```
def rolling_pca(x, window):
    
    # create rolling dataframe
    r = x.rolling(window=window)    
    
    # demand data
    X    = np.matrix(r)
    X_dm = X - np.mean(X, axis = 0)

    #Eigenvalue decomposition (of covariance matrix)
    Cov_X         = np.cov(X_dm, rowvar = False)
    eigen         = np.linalg.eig(Cov_X)
    eig_values_X  = np.matrix(eigen[0])
    eig_vectors_X = np.matrix(eigen[1])

    #transformed data
    Y_dm          = X_dm * eig_vectors_X

    #assign transformed yields
    yields_trans = Y_dm.copy()

    # get PCs
    pc1_yields = x.copy()
    pcas       = yields_trans[:,0:3]
    
    return pcas  

#assign window length
window = 300

rolling_pca(data, window=window)
```

And tried below. Get error: "LinAlgError: 0-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional"

```
def pca(x):
 
    # demand data
    X    = np.matrix(x.values)
    X_dm = X - np.mean(X, axis = 0)

    #Eigenvalue decomposition (of covariance matrix)
    Cov_X         = np.cov(X_dm, rowvar = False)
    eigen         = np.linalg.eig(Cov_X)
    eig_values_X  = np.matrix(eigen[0])
    eig_vectors_X = np.matrix(eigen[1])

    #transformed data
    Y_dm          = X_dm * eig_vectors_X

    #assign transformed yields
    yields_trans = Y_dm.copy()

    # get 3 PCs
    pcas       = yields_trans[:,0:3]
    final_pcas = pd.DataFrame(pcas)
    
    return final_pcas

data.rolling(200).apply(pca)
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated!